# How do I prevent AutoFixture's GuardClauseAssertion from checking the constructor in an inherited class?

Tags: c#, testing, autofixture

I have a class that inherits from the SemanticType class in the [Semantic Type project](https://github.com/mperdeck/semantictypes):

I am trying to test *my* class and ensure that I have a guard clause preventing Null and empty strings from being passed.  However, the test fails because the inherited class, SemanticType, does not have a Guard clause.  How do I coax AutoFixture to only look at the constructor in my ZipCode class?

```
public class ZipCode : SemanticType<string>
{
    public ZipCode(string value) : base(IsValid, value)
    {
        Guard.NotNullOrEmpty(() => value, value);
        Guard.IsValid(() => value, value, IsValid, "Invalid Zip Code");
     }
 }
```

When debugging, the test is failing in SemanticTypes.dll with this message:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in SemanticTypes.dll but was not handled in user code

In other words, there's no Guard clause in the constructor in SemanticType.  Any help you can provide would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the overloads of `GuardClauseAssertion`'s `Verify` that takes a [ConstructorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo(v=vs.100).aspx) as a paramerer.

Then you can further constrain the assertion, by selecting only those constructors belonging into `ZipCode` class:

```
[Test, AutoData]
public void SutConstructorHasAppropriateGuardClauses(
    GuardClauseAssertion assertion)
{
    assertion.Verify(
        typeof(ZipCode).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public));
}
```

Although I don't have access to SemanticType project, the above test should, normally, pass.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I was almost there, but you gave me the push I needed with the BindingFlags.

Comment: +1 To clarify why `GuardClauseAssertion` behaves like it does, when we wrote it, we debated whether it should check non-public members when we designed it, and decided that it should. The reason for that is that now that it checks for non-public members, you can always filter them away, as this answer explains. If it had been designed the other way around, there wouldn't have been an easy way to make it check non-public members. Still, I can see from this question that it's not the most *pit of success*-like behaviour.

Comment: I’m fine with your design decision, i.e., opening things up and filtering rather than too tight to use.